# Can't run photoshop CS2 on Ubuntu 14.04 x86_64

Tags: 14.04, wine, photoshop

I have installed Photoshop CS2 (the free version) on Ubuntu 14.04 x86_64. Photoshop gets started and at the loading splash screen it just freezes at "Initializing tools" and after 30 seconds or so, it just closes. Any help is appreciated.

Wine Version: wine-1.7.19

Comment: Another possible error without going through the winetricks steps is the following:

_Unable to continue because of a hardware or system error. Sorry, but this error is unrecoverable._

I'm just putting this here in case someone has this error. The steps in the answer fixes it.

Comment: I've the same issue after installing on a fresh 14.04 machine this morning.

Comment: Don't bother. I've been using photoshop in a VM for a long time now, and I'm happy. I suggest you do the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The folk at [omgubuntu](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/01/photoshop-cs2-available-for-free-works-fine-in-wine) have a detailed list of steps to make it work, and it does work for me.  I find that I can do what I need to do with Gimp, however.

Comment: You're right, Gimp is awesome considering that it's free. But I'm so used to Photoshop that I'd be lost in Gimp. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: It's not too bad - you will see or find the functions your looking for eventually, and there are books about running gimp at your local library

Comment: Well, I think I can make it work with gimp. Specially since the user interface has the option to be just one window instead of the classic multi-window interface.

Answer (score 1):

Run `winecfg`, in Libraries tab add `twain_32.dll`, press Edit then disable it. That's it!

Answer (score 0):

Another possible error without going through the Winetricks steps is the following: **Unable to continue because of a hardware or system error. Sorry, but this error is unrecoverable**.
In case someone get this error, the solution is here:

https://www.winehq.org/pipermail/wine-users/2008-July/038454.html

It is a permanent fix, you do not need to do it every time you start Photoshop.

(Here is a [mirror](http://pastebin.com/jhbrwxKk))